# How can I create a window like the one in the image below in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, modal-dialog

[please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NDmq.jpg)

I have installed a chrome extension which [is here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctv-screen-sharing/kohfoaokpnbibffipkhanldhanejlgpm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

when i click the extension icon it opens a small window for showing active tab
can anyone tell me how to create that tab or window...

Comment: and it is not a normal modal because it is appearing as a new window and it has a shown the same  minimize , restore button when right clicked!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create same as the above example you can use this extension to view the source code of the extension you mention above.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin?hl=en